# $scope is not available to ng-template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use modal for editing a form, the modal is in ng-template script, but the form data is not displayed when clicking the edit button.
The $scope is not available to the template script.
I have created a Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/V18kjKTZknpPdm2z87fR?p=preview)

```
$scope.setCurrentItem = function (item) {
    $scope.currentItem = item;
};

$scope.edit = function (item) {            //editing item
    $scope.setCurrentItem(angular.copy(item));            
    //$scope.editItem = item;
    openEditModal();
};

<!--html-->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">     
<label for="name">Role: </label>                                
<input type="text" ng-model="currentItem.roleName" required />
</script>
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default ui bootstrap `$modal` uses `$rootScope` as its default scope. But you are assuming it will automatically take the scope of the controller that opened the dialog, which does not happen. But there is a `scope` property that you can set to pass the scope to the ui modal so that it will use that scope and create a child scope out of the provided scope and will be used as the underlying scope for the modal. So have your modal wrapper take the scope property as well in its settings and pass it through.

[From Doc](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

> scope - a scope instance to be used for the modal's content (actually the $modal service is going to create a child scope of a provided scope). Defaults to $rootScope.

Example changes:-

```
  function openEditModal() {
     var modalOptions = {
        closeButtonText: 'Cancel',
        actionButtonText: 'Save role',
        headerText: 'Edit role',
        bodyText: '',
        scope:$scope //<-- Pass scope
    };

    Modal.showModal({ templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html', size: 'lg' }, modalOptions).then(function (result) {
        console.log("save!", result);
    });
  }
```

and in your service:-

```
  /*I just did this here based on my limited understanding of your code*/
  return $modal.open(angular.extend(tempModalDefaults, customModalOptions)).result;
```

From your modal template pass the item back, i am not sure if your template is generic, if so then you may want to take a different approach to transfer the data back:-

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="modalOptions.ok(currentItem)">{{modalOptions.actionButtonText}}</button>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/uwtq38?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you! PSL; I see what was the problem.